# cashu integration with asp.net

Tags: payment-gateway

I have to integrate cashu payment gateway in my web application, I am using the code provided by cashu implementaion guide. I have created a merchant accout on cashu, but unable to find the encryption key option.So, whenever a post the values I get invalid merchant token value error. Can, anyone help me out of this situation!

```
<form action="https://www.cashu.com/cgi-bin/pcashu.cgi" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="merchanttest">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="66a31cd699d8d9cb454df1f6cec30c2c">
<input type="hidden" name="display_text" value="Baseball Hat">
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="CSH">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="125">
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="asdasd-234-asdasd">
<input type="hidden" name="txt1" value="item27">
<input type="hidden" name="test_mode" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Pay with cashU!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not rely on example encryption key since obviously it is wrong and each merchant gets his own key.

Looking at http://docs.whmcs.com/CashU I found following:

"You can find the Encryption Keyword inside your CashU account by going to My Account > Payment Security.
This is where you also need to set the return url, which must be set to:
http://www.yourdomain.com/modules/gateways/callback/cashu.php
The Notification URL should be left blank."

Hope this helps